# Geoserver Mercator to EPSG:4326

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, wms, wmts, mercator

I have external WMS server, which have a layer pusblished in Mercator projection (EPSG:3395). I have this layer set up in Geoserver (2.8.1, GeoTools 14.1).

I need to expose this layer via WMTS in EPSG:4326.

The problem occurs when I try to query it using EPSG:4326 projection.

Basically, whatever I try I run into the following error:

```
Caused by: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: 
Latitude 90°00.0'S is too close to a pole.
```

with varying value depending on the bbox I use.

So far, I've tried the following:

- changing layer's **Native Bounding Box** from [-20037508.3428, -15496570.7397, 20037508.3428, 18764656.2314] to [-20037508.3428, -20037508.3428, 20037508.3428, 20037508.3428] back and forth;
- setting layer's **Lat/Lon Bounding Box** to [-180, -80, 180, 84], [-180, -85, 180, 85] and [-180, -90, 180, 90];
- trying to create custom grid for GWC layer based on EPSG:4326 with bounds of [-180, -80, 180, 84]

It works perfectly well when I query it with EPSG:900913 projection, with blank zones on the top and the bottom of the map. It also works well when I query it via OpenLayers in EPSG:4326, if I don't get past the 90° latitude. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try the combination of `[-20037508.3428, -15496570.7397, 20037508.3428, 18764656.2314]` and `[-180.0000, -80.0000, 180.0000, 84.0000]`? If that doesn't work, perhaps try the geoserver users mailing list with the full backtrace (not just the geotools referencing error).

Comment: @BradHards thanks for the reply. this was the combination I started with. I'm still hoping I've missed some config detail, because the task seems pretty common to me